# Reduce two columns of IDs with a many to many relationship

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, presto, amazon-athena

I have a dataset with two columns of non-unique IDs (ID-A and ID-B respectively).

A single ID-A can have multiple ID-Bs and vice versa. I am trying to generate a third, set identifier using transitivity (calling it ID-C) which is set to the same value for all records with either ID-A or ID-B in common. Two records having neither ID-A nor ID-B in common should only share an ID-C set identifier if there is a transitive chain of records between them.

To visualize, I have something like the first two columns, and want to generate the third column(ID-C)

```
ID-A  ID-B  ID-C
1     1     1
1     2     1
1     3     1
2     2     1
2     4     1
3     4     1
4     5     2
5     5     2
5     6     2
6     7     3
```

I am using Presto SQL inside of AWS Athena, so I cannot use any variables or loops, that I am aware of.

Comment: In a single SQL query this requires recursive CTEs, which your databases do not support.  You will need to loop in an application.

Comment: Yeah.... That's what I was afraid of.